# How to properly ensure termination of a thread that is using a shared Lock?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

In `__main__`, I create a new daemon thread to achieve a non-blocking processing on a shared state protected by a `threading.Lock()`. While everything works fine from the looks of it when the program is running, I sporadically get an exception when quitting the program, i.e. when the daemon thread is supposed to terminate:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'acquire'

The code is roughly as follows:

```
mutex = threading.Lock()

def async_processing(shared):
    global mutex
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        mutex.acquire()
        try:
            shared.modify_state()
        finally:
            mutex.release()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    shared = SomeObject()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=async_processing, args=(shared,))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

    if user_enters_some_command_to_stdin:       
        mutex.acquire()
        try:
            shared.modify_state()
        finally:
            mutex.release()
```

I'm not really at home with Python and am thus maybe not doing this the way it's supposed to be done, but my guess is that somehow a context switch to the thread happens after `mutex` is no longer available. Is this hypothesis true?

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: How do you quit program? By `Ctrl+C`? Or why not manually stop child thread when quitting?

Comment: @Sraw I just let the main run to completion and quit, i.e. I don't quit only on some user interaction (command entered via command line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is adding a flag variable:

```
mutex = threading.Lock()
flag = True

def async_processing(shared):
    while flag:
        sleep(1)
        with mutex:
            shared.modify_state()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    shared = SomeObject()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=async_processing, args=(shared,))
    thread.start()

    if some_user_action:        
        with mutex:
            shared.modify_state()
    flag = False
    thread.join()  # wait for exit.
```